# High speed data logging in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have an application that will be accepting data at speeds up to ~50MB/s. My current setup is to have one thread receiving the data off the network and placing it into a QQueue located in another thread. This QQueue is then emptied into the file. This setup seems to work well on a quad core 2.5GHz i7 but not on a 1.8GHz Xeon with 8 cores. Both have similar amounts of RAM. The problem on the Xeon is there is data loss between the data transmitted on the network and writing to the file. I have a good idea that the data loss is coming from my ability to receive the data from the network. I have to use QUdpSocket to receive data and it is important I receive all data but not necessarily in order. Does anyone have any idea how to increase single thread performance which I suspect to be the issue?

```
void ReceiveThread::readPendingDatagrams() {
    // Process data while socket still has pending datagrams
    while( udpReceiveSocket->hasPendingDatagrams() ) {
        data = new QByteArray;
        // Update the size
        size = udpReceiveSocket->pendingDatagramSize();
        // Reserve the size in the byte array
        data->reserve( size );
        // Store data into qbytearray
        udpReceiveSocket->readDatagram( data->data(), size, &sender,
                                        &senderPort );
        // Send the data to the file thread
        fileWriteThread.addPacketToQueue( data );
    }
}


void FileWriteThread::addPacketToQueue(QByteArray * data) {
    // Lock the mutex
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    // Add the data packet to the queue
    dataQueue.enqueue( data );

    numReceieved++;
    locker.unlock();
    // Wake the thread that is waiting for this
    dataAdded.wakeOne();
}

void FileWriteThread::run() {    
    forever {
        // Lock the mutex
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        // Check if the packet queue is empty
        while( dataQueue.isEmpty() ) {
            // Sleep the thread
            dataAdded.wait(&mutex);
        }
        // Get the data from the queue
        data = dataQueue.dequeue();
        locker.unlock();
        // Write the data to the file
        writeDataToBuffer(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which steps have you taken to determine the bottleneck?

Comment: This question is very generic and not very clear what is the problem.

Comment: At one point I had the receiving thread writing to the QQueue and the file thread not accessing the queue at all until all data was received. At this point I took all data from the queue and wrote to a file. I was still obtaining data loss on the "slower" machine. I am also using QUdpSocket so I attempted to play around with winsock buffer size but that didn't seem to help either.

- Edited the original to try and be more clear

Comment: `data->reserve( size );` is wrong. You need to resize the array. After the `reserve`, the array is still empty!

Comment: data->reserve( size ); This is supposed to be faster than resize. And the array gets data in the udpReceiveSocket->readdatagram() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid repeatedly calling new operator and reserve. Both can be pretty slow. Try to cach and reuse the objects instead. BTW, where do you delete the objects you allocate using new?

Comment: The data is deleted in: writeDataToBuffer(data);
Thanks for the help, I will take these suggestions into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late ;-). But maybe you should consider making the socket receive buffer larger. This is not the QT buffer but the lower level buffer. this can as of QT 5.3 be set with the function setSocketOption, enum QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption.